# convergence of positive term series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let ${x_n}$ be an arbitrary sequence of real numbers. Then

1.$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\vert{x_n}\vert}^p{\lt}{\infty}$ for some $1\lt{p}\lt{\infty   }$ implies  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\vert{x_n}\vert}^q{\lt}{\infty}$ for any $q\gt{p}$

2.$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\vert{x_n}\vert}^p{\lt}{\infty}$ for some $1\lt{p}\lt{\infty   }$ implies  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\vert{x_n}\vert}^q{\lt}{\infty}$ for any $1\le{q}\lt{p}$

3.Given any $1\lt{p}\lt{q}\lt\infty,$ there is a real sequence ${x_n}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\vert{x_n}\vert}^p{\lt}{\infty}$  but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\vert{x_n}\vert}^q=  {\infty}$

4.Given any $1\lt{q}\lt{p}\lt\infty,$ there is a real sequence ${x_n}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\vert{x_n}\vert}^p{\lt}{\infty}$  but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\vert{x_n}\vert}^q=  {\infty}$

1..$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\vert{x_n}\vert}^p{\lt}{\infty}$ implies that ${\vert{x_n}\vert}^p$ must be decreasing sequence and $q\gt{p}$ implies${\vert{x_n}\vert}^q$ $\lt$${\vert{x_n}\vert}^p$ hence $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\vert{x}\vert}^q$ is convergent.

please correct me if i am wrong

2..counter example $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^p}}$

3...first is correct so third is wrong

I am not getting how to conclude for 4th option.

Comment: For the first, observe that $|x_n|^q < |x_n|^p$ may be wrong for the first few elements of $x_n$ (there may be finitely many $n$ such that $|x_n| > 1$). But thereafter your argument is valid.

Comment: For the fourth, consider $x_n = \frac{1}{n^{1/q}}$.

Comment: what is perfect reason for first option?

Comment: There is some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for $n \geq N$ it is $|x_n| < 1$ (because $|x_n|$ is of course converging to zero). Then $\sum_{n=N}^\infty |x_n|^p \leq \sum_{n=N}^\infty |x_n|^q < \infty$, as in your argument, and hence the full series must as well be convergent.